# "How to replace "[" from string in java?"

Tags: java

I want to use the `String::replaceall` method in Java. I have a string which includes `"["` and I want to replace that with `""` but it's showing an error.

```
String str="already data exists = [ abc,xyz,123 ]";
String replacedStr = str.replaceAll("Already Po Exits =", "");
String replacedStr1 = replacedStr.replaceAll("\\[", "");
```

Comment: Just use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-). `replaceAll` is for regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following replace function will replace [ in your string.

```
str.replaceAll("\\[", "")
```

or you can use replace function to achieve the same

```
str.replace("[", "")
```

Comment: Why not just use [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: error got removed but it is still not replacing [ .

Comment: I am able to remove [ from the code. If you want to remove the closing square bracket then you need to add another replace function

Comment: Can you try to rebuild your project. Because the same example works perfectly in my project

Comment: @AliAhmed those are the correct method calls to do the replace. But remember that a String object cannot have its content modified, and replace methods only work by returning a new String with the replacements done in this new String.

Answer (score 0):

For replacing Unclosed character, you need to add escape character while replacing

```
String replacedStr1 = replacedStr.replaceAll("\\[", "");
```

Comment: error got removed but it is still not replacing [ .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function to do this.

```
String replacedStr1 = replacedStr.replace("[", "");
```